# WordPress on OpenShift endlessly send email about updates

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I installed WordPress on my new OpenShift account using the built-in procedure. All went fine, but now every day at fixed hours (8:10 11:10 20:10 23:10) I'm receiving email messages advising that Wordpress has been automatically updated to last version (4.0.1). How can I stop such unsolicited emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop & start your application (not restart) for the WordPress upgrade that you did to take effect.  Then you should stop getting the emails.